# VBA Loop For Each Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, each

I am working on code to basically go through each sheet in my Workbook, and then selection delete and at finish save all worksheets to csv. I don't receive any errors, but it also only save worksheets.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```all
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xDir As String
Dim folder As FileDialog

Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With xWs
   Range("A3").Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.Copy
   Range("AU1").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   Columns("A:AT").Select
   Range("AT1").Activate
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
   Range("A1").Select
   Cells.Replace What:="(puste)", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    End With

xWs.SaveAs Filename:=xDir & "\" & xWs.Name, FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*but it also only save worksheets*"?

Comment: You have `With xWs` but `Range("A3").Select` refers to active sheet . Maybe you need dot ie `.Range()`  `.Columns()` and `.Cells()`

Comment: @SuperSymmetry this code not selection delete in other sheets, it's only delete selection in activate worksheet, but save all sheets in workbook.
Sorry for my language, I don't speak English very well

Comment: @CDP1802 for `with` and dot I have error `Method or data member not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `With` prefix ranges with a dot.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

    Dim xWs As Worksheet, xDir As String, msg As String
    Dim folder As FileDialog
    
    Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        With xWs
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & xWs.Name
            .Range(.Range("A3"), .Range("A3").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
            .Range("AU1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
                 xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Columns("A:AT").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
           
            .UsedRange.Cells.Replace What:="(puste)", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                 ReplaceFormat:=False ', FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
            .SaveAs Filename:=xDir & "\" & .Name, FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
            '.Activate ' optional
            '.Range("A1").Select ' optional
        End With

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Sheets saved :" & msg, vbInformation
End Sub
```